# Selecting element in WebdriverIO based on tag value

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selector, webdriver-io

Consider the following `HTML` sample:

```
<select class="form-control form-input-toggle ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-model="form.fields['ReportingParty.Contact.Title.Text'].value" ng-change="run()" required="" ng-disabled="!editable(form)">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <optgroup label="----------">
        <option value="MR">Mr</option>
        <option value="MRS">Mrs</option>

    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="----------">
        <option value="2LT">Second Lieutenant</option>
        <option value="AB">Able Seaman</option>
        <option value="ABBOT">Abbot</option>


    </optgroup>

</select>
```

How can I select the value as `MR`, or `Second Lieutenant` using WebdriverIO?

I have tried using `.selectByValue([ng-model="form.fields[\'ReportingParty.Contact.Title.Text\'].value "], "MR" )`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use http://webdriver.io/api/action/selectByValue.html

```
browser.selectByValue("#selectbox", "2LT")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
client.click('//*[@id="selectComboId"]/option[@value="2LT"]');
```